# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized error message is encountered when doing load testing in soapui

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui, performance-testing, load-testing

I am doing a simple load testing in soapui with 5 threads and I am encountering this error in the logs: "DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized". I gave soapui the authorization details (using Basic authorization). When I send the request without using load testing, I receive a successful response. The error is encountered only when I execute load testing.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Might seem obvious, but have you tried asking this question on the Smartbear forum?

Comment: It is hard to know without a lot more details, but you should consider it could also be related to an issue in the authorization system you are testing. Depending on how it is authorizing this token, you may be running into some quota of authorization/second or even some database pool limit. The 401 could be just a bad error handling on the server side.